# How do I specify the order of columns within a multi-column index in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating a multi-column index as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Ranking extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    @Index(name = "ranking_ix")
    public Rankable rankable;

    @ManyToOne
    @Index(name = "ranking_ix")
    public Criteria criteria;

    @Index(name = "ranking_ix")
    public double rank;
}
```

However I can't see how to control the order with which the three columns appear within the composite index (which can be required to ensure optimal query performance).  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the notation

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name="Ranking",
    indexes = { @Index(name="ranking_ix", columnNames = { "Rankable", "Criteria" } ) }
    )
public class Ranking extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Rankable rankable;

    @ManyToOne
    public Criteria criteria;

    @Index(name = "ranking_ix")
    public double rank;
}
```

Comment: I assume this would go on the class, however Eclipse is telling me that "this annotation is disallowed for this location" :-/

Comment: @Table does not have "indexes" - see JPA(2) spec 11.1.45

Comment: DataNucleus, so this answer is incorrect?  Perhaps you could contribute an answer?

Comment: @sanity The answer fails to specify whether the `@Table` annotation is `@org.hibernate.annotations.Table` or `@javax.persistence.Table` when the question is tagged both with `hibernate` and `jpa`. Technically, it is also incorrect because the `javax` version does not have an `indexes` field and the `org.hibernate` version does not have a `name` field. So the above construction cannot exist regardless of which one it might be. Overall @toohool answer is more clear and correct.

Answer (score 2):

This can be specified with the org.hibernate.annotations.Table annotation, which is used *in addition to* the javax.persistence.Table annotation:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="Ranking")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
    appliesTo="Ranking",
    indexes = { @Index(name="ranking_ix", columnNames = { "rankable", "criteria", "rank" } ) }
)
public class Ranking extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Rankable rankable;

    @ManyToOne
    public Criteria criteria;

    @Index(name = "ranking_ix")
    public double rank;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a mapping in XML?

Comment: @Takteek: Please open a new question.

Comment: is that Index annotation org.hibernate or javax.persistence?